How to Parallelize Nested Loops in Fortran on a Shared Memory System with OpenMP, Assigning Threads Explicitly to Inner and Outer Loops?
I am working on a Fortran program with nested loops that I want to parallelize using OpenMP. The program runs on a shared memory multi-processor system, and I want the following:
The inner loop to run on nearby threads, optimizing locality.
The outer loop to run on spread-out threads.
Here is the code snippet I am trying to parallelize:
program test
use omp_lib
implicit none

integer(8), parameter :: n = 2**5 +16 

real(8) :: A(n,n)
integer(8) :: threads_A(n,n)
integer(8) :: i, j

do j = int(1,8), int(n,8)
  do i = int(1,8), int(n,8)
    A(i,j) = 1.d0/real(i+j,8)
    threads_A(i,j) = omp_get_proc_num() ! physical thread number
  end do
end do

end program test

For example, if my CPU has 4 cores with one thread each, and I have 4 CPUs, the thread affinity matrix for a matrix A(9x9) should look like this:
threads_A(:,1) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]  (0,1,2,3 are threads of 1st CPU)
threads_A(:,2) = [4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4]  (4,5,6,7 are threads of 2nd CPU)
.
.

And so on for the other CPUs. This matrix shows how threads are assigned to the elements of the matrix A. How can I achieve this thread assignment and parallelize the loops using OpenMP in Fortran?
Can anyone help me with the OpenMP constructs for this, and also provide guidance on specifying the exact thread numbers or affinity for these loops in the program?

Is your real-world matrix so small? If so, then using cores cannot speed this up. Core communication, work-sharing and synchronization is significantly more expensive than this sequential computation (once optimized). It is generally SIMD instruction is the key to speed this up instead.

It is too big, I want to have control over physical proc allocation in omp parallel block. I want computations in same column go to same cpu but each column computations should be in different cpus.

I am confused. What is too big? And why do you want to do that in the first place? This is horrible performance-wise due to false sharing between cores (based on the provided example).

There is no locality gain by distributing individual array elements to threads. When writing to the array with this granularity, the performance will actually suffer, because cache lines are shared between threads on different sockets. Additionally the work distribution is heavily imbalanced with thread 0 having 9 of 81 iterations assigned while most other threads only have 4 iterations assigned.
